# Flutter- how to disable a Button untill the requireed fields are filled

Tags: flutter, materialbutton

I want to disable a button untill all the required fields are filled. I found similar questions here but all answers are based on making the onPressed property to null. But it does not disable the tap effect.

[image]

[image]

I want something like this. On disabled mode, clicking on the button won't even cause a Tap effect. Can someone help with a solution?

Comment: Use IgnorePointer to make your button not work. Also can put that in Opacity widget so user can see it is not active. Have a bool variable that stores the value if your button should be clickable or not. Create a function that checks the values and sets the value of this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a limited number of widgets, you can wrap them in a widget [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html): when its ignoring property is set to true, the sub-widget (actually, the entire subtree) is not clickable.

```
IgnorePointer(
    ignoring: true, // or false
    child: CustomButton(
        onPressed: _login,
        child: Text("Login"),
        ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this widget.set absorb to true when the required field is empty or is not validated.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

In the textField add

`onChanged : (val){ setastate((){});}`

You mustbe already having a TextEditingController for the textfield. For example i shall name it phoneTextController.

Now in the button check the condition

`phoneTextController.text.length > 10`

For example

```
Inkwell(
 onTap:(){
   if(phoneTextController.text.length > 10){
     SendOtp()
    }
}
child: Container(
color: phoneTextController.text.length > 10 ? Colors.blue : Color.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of Flutter's built-in button Widgets, setting the `onTap` to `null` should automatically disable the button and its effect. Now all that remains is to conditionally do this during your `build`. Say, like the other answer, your `TextEditingController` is named `phoneTextController`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Next'),
  onTap: phoneTextController.text.length > 10 ? () => goToNextPage() : null,
),
```

Which will automatically enable the button and add the callback as soon as the condition is met (in this example, the input length is >10.